# Objective-C: Get the UITouch for which the UIEvent was triggered

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, multi-touch, uitouch

I can't find anywhere in the documentation. When this message is called on my subclass of UIView:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

How can I get the touch for which this message was called ?

On both the NSSet and UIEvent I can get only sets of touches, but no unique identifier so I can determine which touch triggered the message.

**PS:** why on hell would they send a NSSet of all touches, and also the possibility to get the same set from `[[event allTouches] anyObject]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get *the* touch, because sometimes multiple touches triggered the message.  If the user has two fingers on the screen, and moves both, you can get a single `touchesMoved:withEvent:` in which both touches are updated.

You need to process every touch in the `touches` set.  If you've disabled multitouch for the view, so that you know there will only ever be one touch in the set, you can use `touches.anyObject` to get the touch.  But if you haven't disabled multitouch, you need to loop over all of the touches in the set.

The message includes a set of touches separate from `event.allTouches` because the user might have three fingers down but only move one or two of them.  The `touches` set only contains the moved touches, but `event.allTouches` contains all of the user's touches, including the touches that have not moved since the last message.

The unique identifier for the touch is the `UITouch` object itself.  When the user puts a finger on the screen, iOS creates a `UITouch` object.  It updates that object as the user moves his finger.  So you can use the `UITouch` object as the key in an `NSDictionary`, or you can attach your own objects to it using `objc_setAssociatedObject`.